# Set BOOL value to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I want to set a BOOL value as **true false** format to a NSMutableDictionary (which will use as a JSON Dictionary of the API Request). I tried both of the following methods. But those are NOT the correct format requested by the API (API needs the BOOL value as true/false type not as 1/0).

```
BOOL isDefault = YES;
[dicTemp setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", isDefault] forKey:@"is_default"];

//[dicTemp setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isDefault] forKey:@"is_default"];
```

Can anyone have an ides

Comment: try to use %d in the stringwithformat

Comment: You could save `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];` and later `[[dictionary objectForKey:@"key"] boolValue];`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`BOOL` can be wrapped in an [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object:

```
dicTemp[@"is_default"] = @YES;
```

(This code is using the newish [Objective-C Literals syntax](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)).

If you are old-fashioned (nothing wrong with that), then the above statement is the same as:

```
[dicTemp setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
            forKey:@"is_default"];
```

To test later:

```
NSNumber *numObj = dicTemp[@"is_default"];
if ([numObj boolValue]) {
    // it was YES
}
```

Comment: I have one Bool variable Like
Bool fbId;
dicTemp[@"keyValue"] = fbId;
This is Not Work please help me ..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Vidhi Start a new question.